# Image uploading fails (getFileDetails is not a function) in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I hope you can help me out on this case. I have a created a function for image uploading with angularJs and i'm keep getting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.element(...).scope(...).getFileDetails is not a functiononchange @ (index):1
```

This is my function inside controller 
//Upload a images

```
        $scope.addImage = function(){
            var f = document.getElementById('file').files.length;
            if(f+$scope.numberOfImages > 5){
                $scope.addImageFail = true;
                $scope.messageErrorAddPicture =
                    "Sorry but you selected too many images. " +
                    "All together with already added images, you can have max 5 images";
                $timeout(function(){$scope.addImageFail = false;}, 4000);
            }else{
                // GET THE FILE INFORMATION.
                $scope.getFileDetails = function(e){
                    $scope.files = [];
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                        // STORE THE FILE OBJECT IN AN ARRAY.
                        for (var i = 0; i < e.files.length; i++) {
                            $scope.files.push(e.files[i])
                        }
                    });
                };
                $scope.uploadFiles = function(){
                    //FILL FormData WITH FILE DETAILS.
                    var data = new FormData();
                    for (var i in $scope.files) {
                        data.append("uploadedFile", $scope.files[i]);
                    }
                    $http({
                        method : 'POST',
                        url : $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/products/addImagesToProduct',
                        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
                        data : $.param({
                            id_product : $scope.id,
                            file : data
                        })
                    }).success(function(data){
                        if(!data.success) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $scope.addImageFail = data.addImageFail;
                            $scope.messageErrorAddPicture = data.messageErrorAddPicture;
                            $timeout(function(){$scope.addImageFail = false;}, 4000);
                        }else{
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                    //objXhr.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
                }
                // UPDATE PROGRESS BAR.
                function updateProgress(e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        document.getElementById('pro').setAttribute('value', e.loaded);
                        document.getElementById('pro').setAttribute('max', e.total);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is my HTML

```
<form ng-submit="addImage()" enctype='multipart/form-data' novalidate>
  <input type="hidden" ng-model="product[0].id_product" name="id" disabled="disabled" />
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file" multiple onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getFileDetails(this)" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<!--ADD A PROGRESS BAR ELEMENT.-->
<div class="bg_light_color_1 relative r_corners progress_bar wrapper">
  <p><progress id="pro" value="0"></progress></p>
  <!--<div style="width:40%" class="bg_color_green_2"></div>-->
</div>
```

So i have two questions:
 1. What i'm doing wrong with image uploading? How to fix my code to make it working.
 2. You see that commented line //objXhr.addEventListener("progress"... How to append this addEventListener to my $http request so i will get the image upload status

If you need any additional information or code, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use already existing file upload module for angular? Check out  https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: If no one answers my question, then i will try out your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem based on @Lokesh yesterday comment
I have included [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) librarie and code is now simplified and it works

my controller now

```
        $scope.uploadFiles = function(files, id_product){
            $scope.files = files;
            if (files && files.length) {
                Upload.upload({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/products/addImagesToProduct',
                    data: {
                        id_product: id_product,
                        files: files
                    }
                }).then(function(response){
                    console.log(response.data);
                    if(!response.data.success){
                        $scope.addImageFail = response.data.addImageFail;
                        $scope.messageErrorAddPicture = response.data.messageErrorAddPicture;
                        $timeout(function(){$scope.addImageFail = false;}, 4000);
                    }else{
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $scope.result = response.data;
                        });
                    }
                },function (response) {
                    if (response.status > 0) {
                        $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
                    }
                },function (evt) {
                    $scope.progress =
                        Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                });
            }
        };
```

HTML

```
    <h4>Upload on file select</h4>

    <button ngf-select="uploadFiles($files, product[0].id_product)" multiple accept="image/*">Select Files</button>
    <br>
    <br>Files:
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="f in files" style="font:smaller">
            {{f.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="bg_light_color_1 relative r_corners progress_bar wrapper" ng-show="progress >= 0">
        <p><progress id="pro" value="0"></progress></p>
        <div style="width:{{progress}}%" class="bg_color_green_2"></div>
    </div>
    {{errorMsg}}
```